# Run PyCharm with more memory limit

Tags: linux, pycharm, linux-mint

I have problems running PyCharm with bigger memory size on Linux Mint Sylvia 18.3. I have a script that requires a lot of memory and pycharm does only allow to edit this via config file.

Example:

https://superuser.com/questions/919204/how-can-i-increase-the-memory-heap-in-pycharm

Problem is that I have PyCharm installed via snap, and snap installations are monted as RO file systems and I can not edit that config. Is there any easy way around this?

Also tried this remounting but does not seem to work for me:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/47538/how-to-make-read-only-file-system-writable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone coming across this in 2023, PyCharm now allows to configure the Memory Heap using the UI: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/increasing-memory-heap.html